# Test Rule alias

Tags: webpack, loader, rules

I would like to transform only files imported from an alias.

Example

```
module: {
  rules: [
    test: /@alias/,
    loader: 'some-loader'
  ]
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@alias': path.join(__dirname, './src/alias')
  }
}
```

This way **some-loader** will transform only files coming from *@alias*, if some of this files are imported without alias, is not going to be transformed be **some-loader**.

Is it possible?